# Id value is not valid for the Document standard controller

Tags: visualforce, standardcontroller

I am trying to upload a csv file and creating object(code) using the contents of file.I have created a custom link on detail page of my custom object(line) like this(on click javascript) - 
window.top.location.href='/apex/Zip_Codes?Id={!Line__c.Id}'

I have also created  class and a vf page to load the csv file. In vf page m using standard controller as Document and extension as my controller class.

But on clicking the custom link currently i am getting the below error-

> Id value a0Sn00000005v0k is not valid for the Document standard
>   controller

As per my observation this error is coming as it is passing 15 digit id to Document object and it is expecting a 18 digit id. What is the solution for this. Please help.thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this is a syntax issue. Because of the standard controller the passed ID should be of type Document. In your case it is of type Line__c. Try to rename the ID parameter to something else, for example lineId.

Comment: i want to pass id of my line object to Document. Document is predefined standard controller for salesforce which i m using to process the document(csv file) uploaded by user.

Comment: Read this article: [Building Visualforce Pages Using Standard Controllers](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Building_Visualforce_Pages_Using_the_Standard_Controller). Especially the following: The standard controller requires record context that can be provided by including a URL parameter named ‘id’ and assigned with a valid 15- or 18-digit record ID. `The record specified by the ID must match the sObject type associated with the StandardController on the page, or an error will be thrown when the page attempts to render` So you need to pass an Document ID instead of the Line__c ID.

Comment: In other words if using standard controller the `ID` parameter is reserved. You have to pass your custom values using other parameter names.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a syntax issue. Because of the standard controller the passed ID should be of type Document. In your case it is of type Line__c. Try to rename the ID parameter to something else, for example lineId.

Read this article: [Building Visualforce Pages Using Standard Controllers](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Building_Visualforce_Pages_Using_the_Standard_Controller). Especially the following:

> The standard controller requires record context that can be provided
>   by including a URL parameter named ‘id’ and assigned with a valid 15-
>   or 18-digit record ID. **The record specified by the ID must match the**
>   **sObject type associated with the StandardController on the page**, or an
>   error will be thrown when the page attempts to render.

So you need to pass an Document ID instead of the Line__c ID

In other words if using standard controller the ID parameter is reserved. You have to pass your custom values using other parameter names.